# Image not visible when computer chooses the choice

Tags: javascript, html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXWPA.png)The Problem is when a computer chooses the choice, the image is not visible while the human choice image is clearly visible. Please help me out to debug where things went wrong. It shows the error ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. However the human choice image is clearly visible.

```js
function rpsGame(yourChoice) {
    console.log(yourChoice);
    console.log(yourChoice.src);
    var humanChoice, botChoice;
    humanChoice = yourChoice.id;
   
    botChoice = numberToChoice(randToRpsInt());
    console.log('Computer Choose ',botChoice)
    
    results = decideWinner(humanChoice,botChoice);
    console.log(results);
   
    message =finalMessage(results);
    console.log(message);
    
    rpsFrontEnd(yourChoice.id,botChoice.in, message);

}

function randToRpsInt() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*3)
}

function numberToChoice(number) {
    return['stone','paper','scissor'][number]
}

function decideWinner(yourChoice,computerChoice) {
    var rpsDatabase = {
        'stone':{'stone':0.5,'paper':0,'scissor':1},
        'paper':{'stone':1,'paper':0.5,'scissor':0},
        'scissor':{'stone':0,'paper':1,'scissor':0.5}
    };
    var yourScore = rpsDatabase[yourChoice][computerChoice];
    var computerScore = rpsDatabase[computerChoice][yourChoice];
    
    return[yourScore,computerScore];
}

function finalMessage([yourScore,computerScore]) {
    if (yourScore === 0) {
        return{'message' : 'You Lost !', 'color': 'red'};
    } else if(yourScore === 0.5) {
        return{'message': 'You Tied !', 'color':'darkgoldenrod'};
    } else {
        return{'message': 'You Won !', 'color': 'green'};
    }
        
}

function rpsFrontEnd(humanImageChoice,botImageChoice,finalMessage) {
    var imageDatabase = {
        'stone':document.getElementById('stone').src,
        'paper':document.getElementById('paper').src,
        'scissor':document.getElementById('scissor').src,
     }
    //removing the imgages after clicking on it 
    document.getElementById('stone').remove();
    document.getElementById('paper').remove();
    document.getElementById('scissor').remove();
    
    var humanDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var messageDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var botDiv = document.createElement('div');
    
    humanDiv.innerHTML = "<img src='" + imageDatabase[humanImageChoice] +"'   height = 150 width = 150 style = 'box-shadow : 0px 10px 50px    rgba(37,50,233,1;'>" 
    
    messageDiv.innerHTML = "<h1 style= 'color: " +finalMessage['color']+";font-size:60px;padding:30px;'>" + finalMessage['message'] + "</h1>"
   
    botDiv.innerHTML = "<img src= '"+ imageDatabase[botImageChoice] + "' height=150 width=150 style='box-shadow:0px 10px 50px rgba(243,38,24,1);'>"
     

    document.getElementById('flex-box-rps-div').appendChild(humanDiv);
    document.getElementById('flex-box-rps-div').appendChild(messageDiv);
    document.getElementById('flex-box-rps-div').appendChild(botDiv);  
    
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vn33v.png)

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `botChoice.in` presumably should be `botChoice.id`

Comment: actuatlly its a project so how can I use as little code as possible? However the problem is that the in the game of stone paper scissor in javascript random image choosen by computer is not visible

Comment: @Turnip still there is no change the console shows "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

Answer (score 0):

rpsFrontEnd(yourChoice.id, botChoice, message);
//replace botChoice.id with just botChoice